# Do I have to logout the user if username or password changes?

Tags: shiro

I am using Apache Shiro for my JSF 2.2 web application and have a form based authentication form (email address as the username and password). I also allow user to edit their profile including their username and password. I noticed that when I update the username (although the user is still authenticated), I don't have access to principal (username) of the user. Right now, I programmatically logout the user after such profile changes and ask them to login again. Is there any other alternative?

Thank you,
Hooman

Comment: This only applies to changing the username. When user only changes the password I can automatically logout the user and login again with her existing username and the new password. The problem still exists with changing the username though, because I only store hashed salted password in the database and therefore cannot automatically authenticate the user with the new username and old password.